# How can I push the derivative through the following sum?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, derivatives

Let $f$ be a probability density and $F$ the corresponding distribution function. In other words $f$ is non-negative, integrates to 1, and $F' = f$. I'm interested in the following:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}F(i+x)-F(i)\stackrel{?}{=}\sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}f(i+x)
$$
I'm doubtful that this result holds in general. But what if I add assumptions such as that $f$ be Lipschitz-continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to show that $\sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}F(i+x)-F(i)$ is a primitive function of $\sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}f(i+x)$.

\begin{align}
& \int_0^x \sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}f(i+t) dt \\
=& \sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} \int_0^x f(i+t) dt \tag{Fubini-Tonelli Theorem} \\
=& \sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} (F(x+i)-F(i))
\end{align}

The result follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.